# Why when I click on the button to cancel the web client download progress I'm getting exception?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

```
private void btnStop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (this.client != null)
                this.client.CancelAsync();
        }
```

In the completed event i have only a return; in the cancel:

```
private void client_DownloadFileCompleted(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Error != null)
            {
                // handle error scenario
                throw e.Error;
            }
            if (e.Cancelled)
            {
                //client.Dispose(); // Method that disposes the client and unhooks events
                return;
                // handle cancelled scenario
            }

            if (url.Contains("animated") && url.Contains("infra"))
            {
                Image img = new Bitmap(lastDownloadedFile);
                Image[] frames = GetFramesFromAnimatedGIF(img);
                foreach (Image image in frames)
                {
                    countFrames++;
                    image.Save(downloadDirectory + "\\" + fname + ".gif");
                }
            }

            label2.Text = "Download Complete";

            string lastUrl = (string)e.UserState;

            listView1.BeginUpdate();
            foreach (ListViewItem li in listView1.Items)
            {
                if (li.SubItems[2].Text == lastUrl)
                {
                    li.SubItems[0].Text = "Downloaded";
                    li.SubItems.Add("Color");
                    li.SubItems[0].ForeColor = Color.Green;
                    li.UseItemStyleForSubItems = false;
                }
            }
            listView1.EndUpdate();

            tracker.NewFile();
            DownloadFile();
        }
```

The exception:

> HResult=-2146233079    Message=The request was aborted: The request
>   was canceled.    Source=DownloadMultipleFiles    StackTrace:
>           at DownloadMultipleFiles.Form1.client_DownloadFileCompleted(Object
>   sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e) in Form1.cs:line 193
>           at System.Net.WebClient.OnDownloadFileCompleted(AsyncCompletedEventArgs
>   e)
>           at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadFileOperationCompleted(Object arg)    InnerException:

Line 193 is:

```
throw e.Error;
```

Inside the completed event.

e.Error = {"The request was aborted: The request was canceled."}

Should I do something in the completed event in the cancel part ? all id othere is a return.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It occurs that  `this.client.CancelAsync();` internally raises not only `Cancelled` flag but also sets `Error` to the exception you see. So the obvious way to fix your code is to swap two checks

```cs
private void client_DownloadFileCompleted(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    // First check for Cancelled and then for other exceptions
    if (e.Cancelled)
    {
        //client.Dispose(); // Method that disposes the client and unhooks events
        return;
        // handle cancelled scenario
    }
    if (e.Error != null)
    {
        // handle error scenario
        throw e.Error;
    }

    ...
```